# Magento issue after updating from 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I have upgraded my Magento version 1.4.2.0 to 1.5.0.1. Every thing is ok, but after clicking on wishlist I get the following error. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
Invalid method Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item::canConfigure(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('canConfigure', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Render/Item/Price.php(47): Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item->canConfigure()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/render/item/price.phtml(29): Mage_Wishlist_Block_Render_Item_Price->getCleanProductPriceHtml()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(216): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(247): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(261): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Abstract.php(355): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/design/frontend/default/magik_computerstore/template/wishlist/sidebar.phtml(46): Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract->getPriceHtml(Object(Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item))
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(216): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(247): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(261): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php(61): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(758): Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Sidebar->_toHtml()
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(525): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(476): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/design/frontend/default/magik_computerstore/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(54): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(216): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(247): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(261): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(758): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(389): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(102): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#27 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1501/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Comment: Are you using the default theme? Or a custom theme based on the 1.4.2 default?

Comment: Your problem is in `/app/design/frontend/default/magik_computerstore/template/wishlist/sidebar.phtml` - follow @[Lee Saferite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990123/magento-1-5-issue/5655041#5655041)'s fix and you should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, it's your custom theme.  Your app\design\frontend\default\template\wishlist.phtml file is calling $this->getPriceHtml() and passing a wishlist item when it expects a product.

Example:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_item);
```

When it expects:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_item->getProduct());
```

But you are assured to have more errors if the theme was written for and older version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your `magik_computerstore` theme was coded for 1.4 and has not been adjusted for 1.5. If it makes calls that are no longer appropriate, errors like this can occur. I would suggest checking with your theme developer for 1.5 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading with deleted block-methods being called form the layout xml files. I removed the lines in the XML configuration that was troubling (top.links rendering would fail)

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by sidebar.phtml in app\design\frontend\default\\template\wishlist.

Please compare to sidebar.phtml in base theme. I'm upgrade our magento themes to 1.5.0.1